# How to add razor view file in Azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I am creating an app which is azure function project and I want to use Razor view in that project,
Is there any templating engine that I should use in azure function?

Comment: Some research on the topic: http://www.luckenuik.net/hosting-your-aspnet-core-razor-pages-inside-azure-functions/

Comment: @AaronHudon link is dead

Comment: @interesting-name-here yeah, looks like he turned off his blog.  too bad.

Comment: I had a samilar issue, I want to reuse my htmlRenderingService in my dedicated dotnet azure function (which is not using MVC and hard to config it to support razor feature).  I have found https://github.com/soundaranbu/Razor.Templating.Core is amazing, it helped to removed all unwanted dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Functions does not provide any built in or special support for Razor or other template engines, so the fact that you're using it shouldn't influence your decision as to what engine to use.

Razor and other template engines do support programmatic rendering, so you should be able to use that approach to get your templates to work in Azure Functions.

Comment: hi, can I have a reference on how to make razor templating work with Azure Functions? I can't get it work, especially when it trying to reference System.Web.MVC, it throw exception saying dll is not found, but it does exist in /bin.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to some advancements in [RazorLight project](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight) and Azure Functions, there is now an option to render Razor.

**Warning** In this example views are compiled at runtime. Consider this if your Azure Functions stop and start often.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Reflection;
using RazorLight;
using System.Linq;

namespace RootNamespace
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            //check which view files have been embedded
            var names = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            names.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

            var engine = new RazorLightEngineBuilder()
              .UseEmbeddedResourcesProject(executingAssembly, "RootNamespace.Views") //'Views' is folder with views 
              .SetOperatingAssembly(executingAssembly)
              .UseMemoryCachingProvider()
              .Build();

            string result = await engine.CompileRenderAsync<object>("View1.cshtml", "foobar model string");

            return new OkObjectResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

`.\Views\View1.cshtml`

```
@model String;
@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}
View1 @Model
```

`.\Views\_Layout.cshtml`

```
Layout
@RenderBody()
```

`.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>  <-- these 3 properties are important
    <PreserveCompilationReferences>true</PreserveCompilationReferences>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Views\View1.cshtml" />
    <None Remove="Views\_Layout.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\View1.cshtml">  <-- in my example views are Embedded Resources
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\_Layout.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="RazorLight" Version="2.0.0-rc.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```