# How to Render Razor Page in Azure Functions via Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-function-app

```cs
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run()
{
    return data != null
    ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Current-Temperature, {data.Current.Temperature}")
    : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request 
    body");
}
```

Here I am returning a value like string or a int.But I need to return a Razor Page.
In templates I am unable to find the Razor Page instead its showing HTML Page and other templates.
Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766965/how-to-add-razor-view-file-in-azure-function -- you can try reviewing the blog post mentioned in that response: http://www.luckenuik.net/hosting-your-aspnet-core-razor-pages-inside-azure-functions/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add razor view file in Azure function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766965/how-to-add-razor-view-file-in-azure-function)

Comment: Not Exactly. @Bryan Lewis